# Using search in grails 3.x web-micro rest call does not work

Tags: grails, microservices

I'm using the web-micro profile from Grails 3.x to write microservices.  I need to be able to search on one of the fields.  I believe in previous versions of grails, you could add the fields to the query string.

http://localhost:3141/zipcode?zip=55509 would return just the zipcode object(s) that had that value for zip.

This does not seem to work in Grails 3.x web-micro.

```
@Entity 
@Resource(uri="/zipcode") 
class ZipCode { 
    static belongsTo = [kingdomGroup : KingdomGroup] 
    String zip 

    static constraints = { 
    }

    String toString() { zip } 
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: `@Entity
    @Resource(uri="/zipcode")
    class ZipCode {
        static belongsTo = [kingdomGroup : KingdomGroup]

        String zip;

        static constraints = {
        }

        String toString() { zip }
    }`

Comment: Thank you for formatting dmahapatro.  I will work on that.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that kingdomGroup is initialized properly?
secondly, confirm the datasource that you're using, and that it has data as expected.

Comment: kingdomGroup is initialized  The rest of the restful interface works fine (well, I haven't tried delete yet).  The get in my question returns the entire database, instead of the records that have zip=55509.